# Emacs shell: outlining input, output, error

Tags: shell, emacs

I am searching for a way to distinguish visually in a shell/comint what the user typed, what was output and what was output by stderr. Is there a mode for this?

(Just to be sure, I am not interested in `ansi-color-for-comint-mode`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Elisp facilities for running asynchronous processes do not provide good support to distinguish the stderr from the stdout output, so currently comint does not let you distinguish the two.
OTOH coming already displays differently the text the user typed (comint-highlight-input face), the prompt (comint-highlight-prompt face), and the process output (no special face, i.e.`default).

Comment: As far as I (vaguely) understand the issue: Currently stdout/stderr is handled by the tty, a distinction between stdout/sterr would be rather a filter-function (kind of a highly reduced handwritten tty).